# Windows - Output Audio to 2 Devices (Using JACK)

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype

I have a bit project I'd like to setup, but am a little stuck on how to go about it.

On Windows 7, how would one go about outputting audio to 2 devices? Essentially, I'm using Studio One for producing music, and would like to output it's audio both to my audio box (Steinberg UR22) and to an  input device in Google Hangouts/Skype. So, my clients could  hear what I'm doing, well as letting it hear it myself (dont worry about mic picking stuff up, I can manage that).

Stereo Mix feature in Windows won't do, as again I'm using an external audio box. I've heard JACK might be able to accomplish this, but no idea how to get it rolling. Would anyone have any advice on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A cheap USB soundcard should help. Skype can take it's audio from a different source, then it's just a matter of setting up the inputs, levels and cabling.

Answer (score 0):

You can send audio to 2 different audio devices with Voicemeeter (www.voicemeeter.com). This is a virtual audio mixer application allowing you to connect all audio sources (physicals or virtual), including Audio Pro application using ASIO driver...